# How inject javascript in web view?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have webView with loaded url, need to inject javascript code in there.

```
    javascript: (function(){
var a = document.createElement('script');
a.type='text/javascript';
a.src=location.protocol+'//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(a);
})();
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Can you use [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascript]?

Comment: I use it, but maybe i use it wrong or wrong javascript code